# How to post 2 more parameters with superagent without urlencoding

Tags: javascript, node.js, coffeescript, superagent

I want to post 2 more parameters with superagent without urlencoding.

I want to send this parameter with superagent.

```
items="[{\"name\":\"\\u5185\\u5bb9\"}]"&user=1
```

I try following curl script, and it works what I want.

```
curl -s -H "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded" -H "X-AAA-HEADER: aaa" -H "X-BBB-HEADER: bbb" -XPOST -d 'items="[{\"name\":\"\\u5185\\u5bb9\"}]"&user=1' http://localhost:3000
```

I wrote following coffeescript code.

```
postitem = (url, items, user) ->
  new Promise((resolve, reject) ->
    request.post(url).set('X-AAA-HEADER', 'aaa').set('X-BBB-HEADER', 'bbb').type('form').send(
      items: items
      user: user).end (err, res) ->
      if err
        reject err
      resj = JSON.parse(res.text)
      resolve resj
  )

promisepost = postitem("http://localhost:3000", '[{"name":"内容"}]', '1')
promisepost.then (result) ->
  console.log result
```

At web server, request from coffeescript was following.

```
items%3D%22%5B%7B%5C%22name%5C%22%3A%5C%22%5C%5Cu5185%5C%5Cu5bb9%5C%22%7D%5D%22%26user%3D1
```

But I want to recieve request following(sent from curl)

```
items="[{\"name\":\"\\u5185\\u5bb9\"}]"&assignees=18
```

How can I fix coffeescript?

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem myself.
change code to be following.

```
.send('items='+items+'user='+user).end (err, res) ->
```